# How to convert Mobaxterm Session to SSH config format or YAML/JSON?

Tags: linux, ssh, mobaxterm

I am using Mobaxterm and having a lot of sessions so I can't manually convert all of them to SSH config format which looks like this:

Mobaxterm

```
K8s-TEST - [127.0.0.1]=#109#0%127.0.0.1%22%tinnd%%-1%-1%%%22%%0%0%0%_ProfileDir_\secret\tinnd.ssh\tinnd.ppk%%-1%0%0%0%%1080%%0%0%1#Mono Nerd Font%14%0%0%0%15%248,248,242%39,40,34%255,128,0%3%-1%0%%xterm%-1%6%0,0,0%85,85,85%249,38,114%221,66,120%166,226,46%157,197,75%230,219,116%209,202,137%102,217,239%122,204,218%174,129,255%179,146,239%0,217,217%200,240,240%245,222,179%255,255,255%80%24%0%1%-1%<none>%%0#0# #-1
```

to -> Linux SSH `.ssh/config`, I just care about `Hostname`, `IP` and `port`,

```
Host K8S-TEST-MASTER-127.0.0.1
    hostname 127.0.0.1
    user tinnd
    port 22
    identityfile "/home/mint/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

or YAML/JSON if we can.

Comment: Just regex a bit?

Comment: After several hours trying Regex, I finally got it, thanks for your advice :D

Comment: Make sure to post whatever you used, so the next person with this question doesn't have to go through this again :)

Answer (score 0):

**1st** `grep "tinnd.id_rsa" moba.sessions`

used to separate SSH session from other sessions like RDP, VNC. If your file only contains SSH session, you can skip this or please change **tinnd.id_rsa**

**2nd** `awk 'match($0, /#109#0.+?(?:bad(*FAIL)|%.+%tinnd)/) { print substr($0, 1, RSTART) substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-14) }'`

You can replace your username with my username **tinnd**

**3rd** `sed 's/\=\#/\ /g' | sed 's/\ -\ /-/g' | sed 's/\=\ \#/\ /g' | sed 's/\ \]/\]/g' | sed 's/\ \[/\[/g' | sed 's/\%/\ /g'`

Then remove spaces, sepecial characters in Hostname if you do have using **`sed`**

**4th** `awk '{ system("storm add " $1 " tinnd@" $2 ":" $3 --id_file "~/.ssh/id_rsa")}`

Finally, add these hosts to .ssh/config using `stormssh` tool, you must install it form **`pip install stormssh`** first

Combine all to a single command

```
grep "tinnd.ssh" moba | awk 'match($0, /#109#0.+?(?:bad(*FAIL)|%..%tinnd)/) { print substr($0, 1, RSTART) substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-14) }' | sed 's/\=\#/\ /g' | sed 's/\ -\ /-/g' | sed 's/\=\ \#/\ /g' | sed 's/\ \]/\]/g' | sed 's/\ \[/\[/g' | sed 's/\%/\ /g' | awk '{ system("storm add " $1 " tinnd@" $2 ":" $3 --id_file "~/.ssh/id_rsa")}
```

Hope this regex helps anybody want to switch from Windows to Linux.